# How to implement a CollectionViewCell that can either display an image or a custom UIView provided as input property?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I have a collectionView cell that should either display an image or an icon that is generated as a custom `UIView` (lets say `IconView`).
 Currently, I implemented this by adding an `UIImageView` and an `IconView` as subviews to a container view.

When an image is provided, the image property of `UIImageView` is simply updated. When a new `IconView` is provided it is currently always added as a subview to the container view. Therefore, before adding, it is first checked whether an `IconView` has already been added, and if so it is removed.

Although this implementation works, it is not very elegant and seems not efficient since it results in scrolling issues when the number of rows increase.

Would there be a better (more efficient) way to implement this for a single CollectionViewCell?

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    internal var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            self.imageView.image = image!
        }
    }

    internal var iconView: IconView? {
        didSet {
            if !(self.iconContainerView.subviews.flatMap{ $0 as? IconView}.isEmpty) {
                self.iconView!.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            self.iconView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.iconContainerView.addSubview(self.iconView!)
            self.image = nil            
        }
    }

    fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView!
    fileprivate var iconContainerView: UIView!
    fileprivate var layoutConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // ContainerView
        self.iconContainerView = UIView()
        self.iconContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.iconContainerView)

        // ImageView
        self.imageView = UIImageView()
        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.iconContainerView.addSubview(self.imageView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.iconContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.iconContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        self.iconContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        self.iconContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // Deactivate non-reusable constraints
        _ = self.layoutConstraints.map { $0.isActive = false }
        self.layoutConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        if let iconView = self.iconView {
            self.imageView.isHidden = true
            self.layoutConstraints.append(iconView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.centerYAnchor))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(iconView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.centerXAnchor))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40))
        } else {
            self.imageView.isHidden = false
            self.iconView?.isHidden = true
            self.layoutConstraints.append(self.imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.leadingAnchor))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(self.imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.trailingAnchor))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(self.imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.topAnchor))
            self.layoutConstraints.append(self.imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.iconContainerView.bottomAnchor))
        }
        _ = self.layoutConstraints.map {$0.isActive = true}
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't use *two* different `UICollectionViewCell`s ?

Comment: The collectionView cell I use is fairly long and the image/icon is the only layout difference. I don't know whether two UICollectionViews would improve performance, since even less cells can be reused. Furthermore, it would require to repeat all constraints in each class and a common parent class. Not very attractive, but if it is the only way I will consider it. But would it really not be possible to display custom views in a single cell?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ad and remove the IconView when setting. Add both in the same spot and change the isHidden, alpha, or opacity or bringSubviewToFront. This is much less main thread intensive.

Comment: Yes, but every time the cell is rendered a complete new "IconView" should be displayed.  Your suggestion would be correct in case only a property of IconView was updated (like I already do for UIImageView that will be set hidden when an IconView is provided). Ideally, IconView should be provided as a property as well... Any ideas?